# Problems when using 'Force Stop' in my Android application. How is staring app in phone different from starting via Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, sharedpreferences

I am hoping to get some general hints on the differences between loading and starting an application on an Android phone via Eclipse, and simply clicking on the application after force stopping it.  Here is the situation.

I have an application that I inherited along with source code.  When I build and transfer the code from Eclipse either through "Debug as..." or "Run as..." all works well.  Today, I decided to try doing a Force Stop on the application.  It stopped.  When I double click on it, it's clear that all is not well.  I'm still investigating, but it looks like SharedPreferences and perhaps other things are messed up.  My question is really this.  What does downloading via Eclipse do that simply launching from the device itself does not do?  Is there a way to duplicate a "clean start" like Eclipse does?  I tried 'clear data' and 'clear cache' in the same menu that Force Stop is.

I realize this is a broad question.  I'm hoping someone might have an 'Aha!' idea that leads me to more research.

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: Since posing the question, I see there is quite a bit of discussion about SharedPreferences and Force Stop.  See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503625/android-sharedpreference-errors-after-force-close?rq=1  I am still confused very much confused as to why force stop and clicking on app would be different from downloading and starting via Eclipse.

Comment: This seems impossible to debug as I just tried having Eclipse attached (but not starting a debug session).  The mere act of having Eclipse attached, and the LogCat scrolling allows me to Force Stop the app, start it again, without problems!  What the heck is going on?

Comment: What exactly does not work?

Comment: Hartok,  Numbers and values that should be in edit boxes are not there.  These numbers appear to be retrieved from SharedPreferences. I base this on examining the source code I inherited.  I am wondering if there is some problem with SharedPreferences when one does a 'Force Stop' and what is different between a 'Force Stop' and

Comment: and loading the code via Eclipse.  I can't tell you more as my attempts to debug have not gone well (see my 2nd comment).thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrghh.... This problem has tripped me up before. The entire problem was that I had introduced this line:

```
android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
```

so as to debug a service that the application is using.  That is I had:

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
    ComponentName name = intent.getComponent();
    String packageName = name.getPackageName();
    return mMessenger.getBinder();
}
```

As far as I know, there is no way to debug the early setup parts of a service without doing this.  Anyhow, of course when you simply force stop the app on the phone and start it, it will just hang at this point (the waitForDebugger).  If you are running from Eclipse, no problem as the debugger is right there!  Thanks to all that looked at and/or commented on the question.